# Possibility of preserving the ultrafilter on $\mathcal{P}_{\kappa}(\lambda)$ in V[G] after forcing with a <$\kappa$ directed closed poset?

Tags: set-theory, filters, forcing, large-cardinals

Suppose we have the ultrafilter definition of a supercompact cardinal. Now, we know if $\kappa$ is supercompact and indestructible by any <$\kappa$ directed closed forcing poset in V then $\kappa$ remains supercompact in V[G] after forcing with a <$\kappa$ directed closed poset.

But then can we say for all $\lambda\geq\kappa$, the corresponding $\kappa$ complete normal ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}_1$ on $\mathcal{P}_{\kappa}(\lambda)$ in V is the same as the corresponding $\kappa$ complete normal ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}_2$ on $\mathcal{P}_{\kappa}(\lambda)$ in V[G] ? If not, can we generate $\mathcal{U}_2$ from $\mathcal{U}_1$ in some way, or is there any type of connection between $\mathcal{U}_2$ and $\mathcal{U}_1$ ?

Comment: Why would the ultrafilters be the same? Clearly $[\lambda]^{<\kappa}$ doesn't change, but typically $\mathcal P_\kappa(\lambda)$ does.

Comment: Yes, I see. Thanks, but then is it possible to build a $\mathcal{U}_2$ from $\mathcal{U}_1$ somehow ? or, are they not connected by any chance ?

Comment: Note that if the forcing changes (for example) $2^\kappa$ from $\kappa^{+}$ to $\kappa^{++}$ then the projection of $\mathcal{U_1}$ to a measure on $\kappa$ concentrates on the set of cardinals $\alpha$ such that $2^\alpha = \alpha^{+}$, while the projection of $\mathcal{U}_2$ to a measure on $\kappa$ concentrates of the set of cardinals $\alpha$, such that $2^\alpha = \alpha^{++}$.